# addign a existing handler method with setOnAction

Tags: java, javafx, hyperlink, event-handling, fxml

I want to assign an existing `handleModellAction` method to a generated Hyperlink with the `setOnAction` method, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code example:-

```
@FXML
private void handleModellAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InEX.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) load.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();

    link = (Hyperlink) event.getTarget();
    model = link.getId();

    stage.setTitle(model);
}

public void addNeuesModell(String bauart, String modelName){
    modelHyperlink = new Hyperlink();
    modelHyperlink.setId(modelName);
    modelHyperlink.setText(modelName);
    modelHyperlink.setOnAction(#handleModellAction);
}
```

Does somebody know how to do this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can do it from inside sceneBuilder, you go to the modelHyperLink control, and you modify the setOnAction parameter, or else you do it from the fxml file.

Comment: This would do it if this is a fix Hyperlink, but I want to add this Hyperlink to an existing VBox everytime I klick a Button. So I have to do it like this.

Comment: You don't really need to, since it is the same handler method you are assigning each time, you just need to define it once and then you can add it however you want to the VBox.

Comment: It is more complicated than this I guess. I have an other administration window where I want to decide to witch VBox I want to add the link. Additional to this link I also want to add an imageview.

Comment: But it works with the answer below :)

Comment: I just didn't get what part was dynamic i guess but yeah was gonna put the same think XD setOnAction with your function inside :3

Comment: :D yes I didn't implement it yet so it was difficult to explain. But thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to call the `setOnAction` method on the `modelHyperlink` and pass as parameter an anonymous class as a handler, where in you could transfer the logic of your `handleModellAction` method. Below you can find an example:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
link.setText("http://example.com");
link.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        FXMLLoader load = new 
        FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InEX.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) load.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

        link = (Hyperlink) event.getTarget();
        model = link.getId();

        stage.setTitle(model);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining

```
 <HyperLink fx:id="myLink" onAction="#handleModelAction"/>
```

you can use just:

```
 <HyperLink fx:id="myLink"/>
```

Then in the code:
refactor your handleMethod like this:

```
private void handleModellAction() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InEX.fxml"));
        Parent root = load.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
```

after that:

```
myLink.setOnAction(action -> {
            try {
                handleModellAction();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Then you can use that `handleModellAction()` anywhere you want in any button, hyperlink and so on..